# I have a login view that is presented on app launch. For a split second before it loads I see it's parent view. How can I stop this?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, swift

**If a user is logged out then the login view is presented:**

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if PFUser.currentUser() == nil {
        presentLoginViewController()
    }
}

func presentLoginViewController() {
    let loginViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginViewControllerSB") as LoginViewController
    self.navigationController?.presentViewController(loginViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

The controller the methods above reside in present the login view controller so obviously needs to be loaded before the login view controller can be presented. Moving to viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear makes no difference and gives me a warning about unbalanced views anyway.

I had thought about loading from the app delegate but I still need to load from a view so not sure how this can be done.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I handle this is:

- I have two navigation controller flows in my Storyboard. One is connected by default as the root view controller of the application. The other is my login flow.
- In `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, I check to see if the user's credentials are present/valid. If they are, I do nothing, so my standard app flow happens. If they aren't, I instantiate the login view controller from the storyboard (using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`) and set it as the root view controller.
- At the same time, I set up my app delegate as a delegate for the login view controller, so that it can send me events.
- On a successful login (notified to the app delegate by the login view controller), I re-instantiate my app's "normal flow" view controller and reset *that* as the root view controller.

You can make the transitions between these view controllers smooth by animating them yourself. For example, when my login flow is done, this is how I re-instantiate the normal view controller in my app delegate so I get an nice "flip around".

```
        UIView.transitionWithView(
            window!,
            duration: 0.5,
            options: .TransitionFlipFromRight | UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowAnimatedContent | UIViewAnimationOptions.LayoutSubviews,
            animations: {
                self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
            },
            completion: nil
        )
```

This whole approach seems to give a nice glitch-free flow to the login view controller and back again.

To help illustrate, here are my two relevant functions from my AppDelegate:

```
func loginSuccessful() {
    assert(user.hasCredentials, "No credentials detected on successful login")

    if let navigationController = window?.rootViewController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("homeNavigationController") as? UINavigationController {
        window?.rootViewController = navigationController

        UIView.transitionWithView(
            window!,
            duration: 0.5,
            options: .TransitionFlipFromRight | UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowAnimatedContent | UIViewAnimationOptions.LayoutSubviews,
            animations: {
                self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
            },
            completion: nil
        )

    }
}

// Bits of our main flow (settings screen, etc.) can call this to notify us that our 
// credentials have been invalidated. We'll dump the main flow and pop up our
// login flow instead.
func credentialsInvalidated() {
    if let navigationController = window?.rootViewController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("welcomeNavigationController") as? UINavigationController {

        if let welcomeViewController = navigationController.topViewController as? WelcomeViewController {
            welcomeViewController.delegate = self
        }

        UIView.transitionWithView(
            self.window!,
            duration: 0.5,
            options: .TransitionFlipFromLeft | UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowAnimatedContent | UIViewAnimationOptions.LayoutSubviews,
            animations: {
                // Animate the navigation bar, too, otherwise it's a bit of a
                // jarring disappearance.
                navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

                self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
            },
            completion: nil
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything is working as expected but with the animation nothing happens but a normal slide down.

Comment: Hrm. Seems odd. If you're replacing the root view controller of the window in the app delegate, I'd expect it to work. If it helps, I'll reproduce my exact code; it'll have things you don't need in it, but it might be helpful for seeing exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: This is how my delegate method looks: http://pastebin.com/simXu92u didLogin() is fired on successful submission and login of form.

Answer (score 1):

I have hit this problem in the past. One solution is to insert another viewcontroller in front of your initial one that displays a view that matches your launch image (i.e Default.png).

Then, while that is on display, decide whether to present your login screen or your already-logged-in screen.

Comment: I liked this idea but Matt's had the edge. I originally wanted to let my app delegate take charge in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Make the function call to `presentLoginViewController` in `viewWillAppear`, and not `viewDidAppear`. viewWillAppear gets called just before the view is drawn. Therefore, if you don't have a user, it will present the login view before it gets drawn to screen.

Hope this helps